# Photon transmission

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, waves

I want to know exactly how light travels. Are each photon in a light beam traveling in a cosine function? I'm confused because only when it goes through polarization that it starts to show this type of function. And if it propagates would there be some type of destructive interference happening.
Also, how does the electric field affect the light and does light have an electric field component to it. If so how does that travel?

It would be nice if an image is provided.

Comment: Photons are local measurements on the field and it makes little sense to assume that they travel, at all. What "travels" is a wave function, which is a continuous object. I think you might want to understand Maxwell's equations in detail, first, before you attempt to understand the quantum picture.

Comment: @CuriousOne, I think it's unfair to new members for you to say sentences like your first sentence, "Photons are local measurements on the field and it makes little sense to assume that they travel, at all," without disclosing that such statements are borne of your own personal pet-theory. This is something that really needs to change. You seem to think it's acceptable to hound and plague any questions or answers even the mere subject of which contradict your quirky little idea.

Comment: @DavidReishi: I think it might be more constructive if you wrote an answer to the OP... preferably with the correct physical ontology. I am sure you can explain better than me how single photons interfere with themselves while taking all possible paths in the entire universe.

Comment: If you want to get a good understanding of what is going on here, you may also want to read "QED: The strange theory of light and matter" by Richard Feynman. It's a short book that introduces you to the path integral formulation of quantum mechanics, but without any of the math. It's an easy read and it will get you conceptually very close to what the modern theory of the electromagnetic field looks like.

Comment: @CuriousOne, "If you want to get a good understanding..." That's more like it. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidReishi: In terms of educational value there is no better way to get people off the "photon is an object" delusion than the Santa Clause and his reindeer sled interpretation of quantum mechanics, which is what the path integral formalism is, if you take it literally. For the more mathematically inclined it will be obvious that it's just an analog to the Green's function, but for a certain type of partial differential equation.